# Gulp.js trouble installing, cannot find module 'fetch.js'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did an npm install and it generated a node_modules folder on my folder with only a gulp-livereload subfolder in it. My package.json has the following devDependencies:

```
   .....
   "devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "^3.8.8",
   "gulp-livereload": "^2.1.1"
 }
}
```

When doing npm install/update, it is not generating the gulp folder and also giving me the error message:

```
> v8flags@1.0.1 install C:\Users\SLowe\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags
> node fetch.js


module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\SYoung\fetch.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
npm ERR! v8flags@1.0.1 install: `node fetch.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8flags@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8flags package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node fetch.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8flags
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program    Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "--save-dev" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\SYoung
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any help is appreciated. I am very new to nodejs.

Comment: See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/774

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the new gulp release (3.8.9) isn't compatible with v8flags. Try changing the package.json to

```
   .....
   "devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "3.8.8",
   "gulp-livereload": "^2.1.1"
 }
}
```

If 3.8.8 doesn't work, 3.8.7 worked for me.

Comment: This did install the gulp, but it's not recognizing the 'gulp' command?

Comment: @user3757305 You would need to install gulp globally first. Try `npm install -g gulp@3.8.8`

Comment: you are awesome! Thank you. It totally fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, changing gulp to 3.8.8 helped me too.

I also installed gulp 3.8.8 and everything is now working fine.

```
npm install -g gulp@3.8.8
npm install gulp@3.8.8
```